# Question about proof for why every partial order on a nonempty finite set has a minimal element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, order-theory

The proof goes as follows:

> Proof. Let $R$ be a partial order on a set, $A$. For any element, $a ∈ A$, let $g(a)$ be the set of elements “less than or equal to $a$”, that is, $g(a)::=R\{a\}\cup\{a\}$.
>
> Now if $bRa$, then transitivity of $R$ implies that $g(b) ⊆ g(a)$. Also, if $bRa$ and $b \ne a$, then  $a\notin g(b)$ since $R$ is antisymmetric, and so $g(b) ⊂ g(a)$. So if $a$ is not minimal, then there is some $b$ such that $g(b) ⊂ g(a)$. If $A$ is finite, this implies that $|g(b)| < |g(a)|$.
>
> So if $A$ is finite, the Well Ordering Principle implies that there must be an $a_0$ such that $g(a_0)$ has minimum size. So no $g(b)$ can be smaller than $g(a_0)$, which means $a_0$ must be minimal.

I do not understand the relevance of the middle paragraph. I can intuit why a partial order on a non-empty finite set has a minimal element. But I thought that all you would need to show that some minimal element exists is the Well Ordering Principle. I do recognize that partial orders can have more than one minimal element (say in acyclic directed graphs)--is the paragraph in the middle meant to address that somehow?

One  other question: why does transitivity of $R$ imply $g(b) \subseteq g(a)$?

Super confused and appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: You might explain why you "thought all you would need to show that some minimal element exists is the well-ordering principle." Did you think that the well-ordering principle, which is about natural numbers, could be directly applied to other partially ordered sets?

Comment: The well-ordering principle applies only to the natural numbers. How were you going to apply it to a poset? The above argument is to say there is an $a$ so that $|g(a)|$ is minimal. $|g(a)|$ is a natural number. So we can find an $a$ so that $|g(a)|$ is minimal by the WOP.

Comment: "A $\not\exists g(b)$" makes little sense. Do you mean $a\notin g(b)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes. Sorry that was a typo on my part. And thank you guys. I forgot that the well-ordering principle only applies to natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll answer the second question first. Suppose that $b\mathrel{R}a$. If $x\in g(b)$, then either $x=b$, in which case $x\mathrel{R}a$ and hence $x\in g(a)$, or $x\mathrel{R}b$. But $b\mathrel{R}a$, so by transitivity $x\mathrel{R}a$, and hence again $x\in g(a)$. Thus, every member of $g(b)$ is a member of $g(a)$, i.e., $g(b)\subseteq g(a)$.

The point of the second paragraph is to arrange a situation in which the Well Ordering Principle actually applies. It says that any non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element, so in order to use it, we must have a non-empty set of natural numbers. This set is $\{|g(a)|:a\in A\}$, the set of sizes of the sets $g(a)$ for $a\in A$. Since $A$ is finite, and $a\in g(a)$ for each $a\in A$, each $|g(a)|$ is in fact a positive integer. The Well Ordering Principle now says that there is some $a_0\in A$ such that $|g(a_0)|\le|g(a)|$ for each $a\in A$: $|g(a_0)|$ is the smallest member of the set $\{|g(a)|:a\in A\}$ of positive integers.

Now suppose that $a_0$ is not minimal in $A$. Then there is some $b\in A$ such that $b\mathrel{R}a_0$ and $b\ne a_0$. But then $g(b)\subseteq g(a_0)$ and $a_0\in g(a_0)\setminus g(b)$, so $g(b)\subsetneqq g(a_0)$, and therefore $|g(b)|<|g(a_0)|$. This contradicts the minimality of $|g(a_0)|$, thereby showing that no such $b$ can exist and hence that $a_0$ is minimal in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

(I prefer to write $x\prec y$ instead of $(x,y)\in R$)

The well-ordering principle is applied here to the set of cardinalities $|g(a)|$ as $a$ varies. Since $A$ is finite, these numbers are all $\in\mathbb N_0$ and hence we apply the well-ordering principle only to $\mathbb N_0$.

The purpose of the middle paragraph is to establish that $a$ with minimal number $|g(a)|$ (with respect to the usual total order $<$ on $\mathbb N_0$) is also itself minimal in the sense of the given partial order $\prec$ on $A$.

Here's why transitivity of $R$ implies that $g(b)\subseteq g(a)$ if $b\preceq a$: Let $x\in g(b)$, that is $x\preceq b$. As also $b\preceq a$, we have $x\preceq a$ and hence $x\in g(a)$.

Comment: Hey sorry, I'm not familiar with $\mathbb N_0$. What does that refer to?

Comment: @wcarvalho $\mathbb N$ is generall yused to denote the set of natural numbers. As some prefer to have $0\in \mathbb N$ and others prefer $0\notin\mathbb N$, I use $\mathbb N_0$ to stress that this should be the version *with* $0$.